# How to create Pipeline in azure synapse analytics project Using Rest API?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-synapse

1. We are using Dot Net environment and we are trying to create Pipeline using Rest API.
2. We have Dot Net SDK but we don't want to go with this.

Comment: You can refer to [How to start Synapse Pipeline from Rest API](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics/how-to-start-synapse-pipeline-from-rest-api/ba-p/1684836). 
As you have already started a discussion on MS Q&A, posting the link here for reference to help other community members. You can refer to [How to create pipeline in Azure Synapse Analytics using Rest API Using Dot net C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/579910/how-to-create-pipeline-in-azure-synapse-analytics.html)

Comment: This reference link is about start pipeline which is already there but we are looking for create pipeline where we will pass Json data as request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pipeline - Create Pipeline Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/pipeline/create-pipeline-run)  REST API to create a run of a pipeline.

For step by step by using the Synapse REST APIs - refer to [How to start Synapse Pipeline from Rest API](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics/how-to-start-synapse-pipeline-from-rest-api/ba-p/1684836).